# Rails Active support concern included do : "uninitialized constant" error when using "includer" constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

**Disclaimer : I know that it's a very bad pattern, I just want to understand why I have the following behaviour and the mechanics behind it.**

- Lets have one class with some constants / methods
- one concern
- one monkey patch that include that concern into my first class

I put all of the following in one rails model (under app/modela/a.rb)

```rb
class A
  MY_CONST = "const"

  def self.hello
    "world"
  end
end

module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    byebug # Here I want to try many things
  end
end

class A
  include MyConcern
end
```

Then I open my console and run the following to load my class : 
`[1] pry(main) > A`

First I'm my `A` Class is loaded, then the `MyConcern` module, then the monkey patch.
When I enter my byebug I have some weird behaviour

```
(byebug) self
A                # Important : I'm in the scope of my A class
(byebug) hello
"world"          # so far so good, my A class is loaded and have a world class method
(byebug) A::MY_CONST
"const"          # Obiously this is working
(byebug) self::MY_CONST
"const"          # When I Explicitly access it through `self`, it's also working
(byebug) MY_CONST
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant MyConcern::MY_CONST

nil              # Here for some reason, and that's what I want to understand, I can't access my const, even if `self == A`
```

I want' to know why constant are not working the same way. Why ruby isn't able to find this const. My scope is my `A` class, `self == A`, so why can't I access my constant?

*ps : Rails.version => "6.0.0"*

Comment: When you use MY_CONST, it tries, as shown, to find the constant inside the concern class, and not inside the A scope. Remember that inside the 'include' scope, you're still theoretically inside MyConcern. To understand why this happens exactly we'd need to dig inside Concern's `included` source code, which does all sorts of magics. Most likely this has more to do with ActiveSupport's Concern than with ruby.

Comment: The self == A is misleading I guess